# how to call a function automatically on all pages by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to call a function automatically on all pages and I have 300+ pages on my application. I want my function to run automatically after 10 minutes on all pages. I don't want to use cron jobs because it reduces the speed of the server, so I want to trigger it on the Client-side by using JavaScript.

```
<script> 
  setInterval(function(){ myFunction() }, 5000);
  function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Function to do what? jQuery  can't reproduce a cron job on server. Question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a JS file, for example `interval.js`, and include it on all your pages within the `<head>` tag, like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/file/interval.js" type="application/javascript">
```

This file should not have the `<script>` tags, and **do not forget to include the jQuery file first, or else it won't work, even before the file that contains your function (if you want the function to be in another file, that is)**.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. really help full for me

Comment: You are welcome. I believe that your function uses AJAX, right? I mean, if you want to do something server-side... in case you are not, well, just do some research on that. I'll just assume you do know the difference between client and server sides and you're just trying to find a workaround.